# Default value for non existing keys in dictionaries

Tags: vimscript, dictionary

Is there a way to return a default value if a key is not present in a dictionary?

For example, say that I have `mydict = {'foo':1, 'bar': 2}`. I want that if I call e.g. `:echo mydict['apple']` I get a default value back, e.g. `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `get()` function, see `:h get()`

```
let mydict = {'foo':1, 'bar': 2}
echo get(mydict, 'apple', 0)
```